# CC Tweaked, Im trying to make a quarry program but im gettting a error about Comparing a number with a string, but both values are numbers

Tags: lua, computercraft

The error I get:

> query.lua:25: attempt to compare number with string

The rest of my code - I'm not sure why its not working, because I made sure that both values were in fact numbers, and the error still keeps happening, I have tried looking it up, and I cant find a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
print("Enter L,W,H values")
x = read()
y = read()
z = read()

length = 5
width = 5
height = 5

length = x
width = y
height = z

volume = length * width * height
print(volume.." blocks to mine")
turtle.refuel()
turtleFuel = turtle.getFuelLevel()
fuelNeeded = turtleFuel - volume
if fuelNeeded >= 0 then
    print("Enough Fuel Detected")
else
    print("not Enough fuel, error,"..fuelNeeded..", fuel required "..volume)
end
length1 = length
while length1 > 0 do
    turtle.forward()
    length1 = length1 - 1
end
```

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(type(length1))` right before `while length1 > 0 do`?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `"5"` and `5`? Do you know what `tonumber` is?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i know that "5" would be a string, and 5 would be a number, and i tried tonumber, but it just gave me the same error anyways, i just tried the other code you suggested, it told me it was a string, but in the editor it tells me its a number

Comment: What do you mean by "in the editor it tells me its a number"? How exactly is it telling you that?

Comment: Can you post the exact code you tried when you tried to use `tonumber`?

Comment: sorry, i should have clarified, that's my fault, i have the code open in visual studio code to make writing the code easier, and when i hover over it, it tells me its considered a number

Comment: I wonder that read() is a global. To see what your ```x y z``` will be at the end if only ```read()``` is used try in a Lua console: ```type(io.read())``` and input a number - And to convert it to a number on the fly: ```type(tonumber(io.read()))```

Answer (score 0):

In Computercraft, `read()` returns a string. You should change the first few lines of your code:
Instead of

```
x = read()
y = read()
z = read()
```

write

```
x = tonumber(read())
y = tonumber(read())
z = tonumber(read())
```

Do note, that [`read()`](https://tweaked.cc/module/_G.html#v:read) is not the same as `io.read()`. One is a standard Lua function (which is also implemented in Computercraft) and `read()` is a function created specifically for CC computers and that can take a few extra parameters, and that you can use to do a few tricks once you get more advanced. (I am saying this because someone in the comments mentioned checking `io.read()`)

Also, you mentioned that you "checked the type of the variable in the editor". Lua is a dynamically typed language, and the type of a variable CANNOT be known before the program is actually run. What your editor is probably doing is guessing the type of the variable based what it expects your program to do. These guesses are almost always inaccurate. That's why you should understand what your program is doing, and not rely on your editor. If you want to be extra sure, you want to run some tests, or the type of the variable simply is not known before the program is actually executed (because it may vary), you can use `type()`, like you have, to check its type at runtime. `type()` returns a string, representing the type of the variable:

```
type(nil)                         ---> nil
type("helloworld")                ---> "string"
type(42)                          ---> "number"
type(function()print("HELLO")end) ---> "function"
type({1,2,3})                     ---> "table"
```